# RVM / ZSH - Always shows "Upgraded http://rubygems.org/ to HTTPS" when gem installing

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm curious why it keeps showing this message any not doing anything about it. Is m RVM is setup incorrectly?

[image]

I'm using zsh and have `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` in my .zprofile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this files:

- `~/.gemrc`
- `/etc/gemrc`

it has nothing to do with rvm